# Rewrite rule to simplify codeigniter url for REST api

Tags: php, .htaccess, api, codeigniter, rest

I am writing a REST api in codeigniter using https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver REST controller library. I have written my controller inside `application/controllers/api/v1` and override the Router class to allow multiple sub-folders inside controllers.

Now I want to access the services as
http://api.domain.com/v1/user/11 instead of 
http://api.domain.com/api/v1/user/11

I have tried following htaccess rule

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^api\.domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php/
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /index.php/api/$1 [QSA,L]
```

But it seems to be not working because REQUEST_URI in the $_SERVER global variable is set to `v1/user/11` instead of `api/v1/user/11` so codeigniter is unable to find the controller.

Is there a way to achieve the requirement except setting the altering REQUEST_URI in index.php?

I do NOT want to do permanent redirect.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A route rule as below should help:

```
$route['v1/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'api/v1/$1/$2';
```

If v1 is supposed to change like v1, v2 in future, then something similar to below will help:

```
$route['v(:num)/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'api/v$1/$2/$3';
```